# How to exclude Pods from Code Coverage in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, testing

Is there a way to **exclude** Pods from Code Coverage?
I would like to see Code Coverage only for the code I've written.

Not that it should matter, but I'm using Xcode 8.

Comment: Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40102012/code-coverage-with-cocopods-libary-ios-unit-test

Answer (score 36):

These steps will help:

**1.** add these lines to Podfile

```
# Disable Code Coverage for Pods projects
post_install do |installer_representation|
    installer_representation.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['CLANG_ENABLE_CODE_COVERAGE'] = 'NO'
        end
    end
end
```

**2.** run `pod install`

Now you won't see pods in test coverage.

**Note:** It only excludes Objective-c pods but not Swift

Comment: Fab solution  thanks! how can you exclude 'C' files if they exist in the pods as well ?

Comment: How do you exclude swift files also? Anyone?

Answer (score 23):

**XCode 10 Update**

In Xcode 10 you can set which targets you want to enable code coverage for in

Edit Schemes > Test > Options

Just select 'Gather coverage for some targets' and add your main project.

[image]

Comment: Man U are *Legend* 10+

Answer (score 10):

To disable coverage for swift code you can use a wrapper for SWIFT_EXEC (I verified this so far with Xcode 9.3). Hence the complete solution (incl. Swift) would be the following:

Append to your Podfile (and invoke `pod install` after that):

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |configuration|
      configuration.build_settings['CLANG_ENABLE_CODE_COVERAGE'] = 'NO'
      configuration.build_settings['SWIFT_EXEC'] = '$(SRCROOT)/SWIFT_EXEC-no-coverage'
    end
  end
end
```

Place the following script (name it SWIFT_EXEC-no-coverage) at the root of your source tree (chmod +x as necessary):

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use Getopt::Long qw(:config pass_through);

my $profile_coverage_mapping;
GetOptions("profile-coverage-mapping" => \$profile_coverage_mapping);

exec(
    "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc",
    @ARGV);
```

Here's a link to the corresponding gist: https://gist.github.com/grigorye/f6dfaa9f7bd9dbb192fe25a6cdb419d4

Comment: Worked for me. Once small note, the file needs to be placed in the Pods directory for this to work. For project root, change to '$(SRCROOT)/../SWIFT_EXEC-no-coverage'

Answer (score 6):

1. Click on your Pods project in the Project Navigator on the left
2. On the right hand side, open project and target list if it's not already open; then click on the Pods project name (NOT the targets).
3. Click Build Settings.
4. In the search bar, search for "CLANG_ENABLE_CODE_COVERAGE".
5. Change "Enable Code Coverage Support" to NO.
6. Re-run test.

Comment: You shouldn't ever be changing the Pods project as these settings will get lost on next `pod install/update`. The solution @tung-fam is the correct way of doing it.

Answer (score 3):

If you are developing a pod and want to have code coverage just for yours:

```
    # Disable Code Coverage for Pods projects except MyPod
    post_install do |installer_representation|
      installer_representation.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        if target.name == 'MyPod'
          target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['CLANG_ENABLE_CODE_COVERAGE'] = 'YES'
          end
        else 
          target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['CLANG_ENABLE_CODE_COVERAGE'] = 'NO'
          end
        end
      end
    end
```

Comment: You could also just add `next if target.name == 'MyPod'` as the 3rd line of the answer @tung-fam gave.

Answer (score 0):

Based on answer of @Tung Fam adding exclusion list for some pods

```
# Disable Code Coverage for projects listed in excluded_pods

excluded_pods = ['Pod1', 'Pod2', 'Pod3']

post_install do |installer_representation|
    installer_representation.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        next if !excluded_pods.include?(target.name)

        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['CLANG_ENABLE_CODE_COVERAGE'] = 'NO'
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to remove it works for both Swift and objc Pods

```
 post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          
          # remove code coverage
          config.build_settings['CLANG_ENABLE_CODE_COVERAGE'] = 'NO'
          config.build_settings['ENABLE_CODE_COVERAGE'] = 'NO'
        end
    end
  end
end
```